# Problema com Regex e Java

Tags: java, regex

o meu problema é resolver é remover uma substring de uma string mas ignorando acentos, espaços e eventuais caracteres especiais. Vou colar os cenários de teste que fica mais fácil de entender o problema.

```
    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    public class StringUtilTest {
        @Test
        public void deveTestarRemoverAcentosEspacos() {
            assertEquals("Maca", StringUtil.removerAcentosEspacos("Maçã"));
            assertEquals("Macadoamor", StringUtil.removerAcentosEspacos("Maçã-do amor"));
            assertEquals("MarcaTeste", StringUtil.removerAcentosEspacos("Marca Test'e"));
        }
        @Test
        public void deveTestarRemoverSubstring() {
            assertEquals("texto texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("texto texto a ser removido texto", "texto a ser removido"));
            
            assertEquals("texto texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("texto texto á ser removido texto", "texto a ser removido"));
            assertEquals("texto texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("texto textoaserremovido texto", "texto a ser removido"));
            assertEquals("texto texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("texto texto a s'er removido texto", "texto a ser removido"));
            assertEquals("texto texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("texto texto a ser-removido texto", "texto a ser removido"));
            
            assertEquals("texto texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("texto texto a ser removido texto", "texto á ser removido"));
            assertEquals("texto texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("texto texto a ser removido texto", "textoaserremovido"));
            assertEquals("texto texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("texto texto a ser removido texto", "texto a s'er removido"));
            assertEquals("texto texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("texto texto a ser removido texto", "texto a ser-removido"));
            
            assertEquals("tex'tó texto texto-texto", StringUtil.removerSubstring("tex'tó texto texto á ser removido texto-texto", "texto a ser removido"));
        }
    }
```

A implementação que eu tenho falha no último teste, pois não consigo voltar para o texto original.
Alguma ideia?

```
    import java.text.Normalizer;
    
    public class StringUtil {
        public static String removerAcentosEspacos(String str) {
            String retorno = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
            retorno = retorno.replaceAll("['\s-]", "");
            return retorno;
        }
    
        public static String removerSubstring(String texto, String textoASerRemovido) {
            texto = removerAcentosEspacos(texto).replaceAll(removerAcentosEspacos(textoASerRemovido), " ");
            return texto.replaceAll("\s+"," ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dentro de `removerAcentosEspacos`, o `replaceAll("['\\s-]", "")` remove os espaços, hífens e apóstrofos, então `tex'tó` é transformado em `texto`, e `texto-texto` vira `textotexto`, por isso o texto original se perde. Se não quer isso, então não remova esses caracteres do texto original (somente do texto a ser substituído, talvez - não entendi se é isso mesmo)

Comment: Um detalhe é que dentro de strings o atalho `\s` teria que ser escrito como `\\s` - não sei se foi erro de digitação